# args doesn't work in grunt-protractor-runner

Tags: javascript, protractor, webdriver

there!
I try to configure and start Gruntfile.js with chromeOptions and args,

```
        capabilities: {
          browserName: 'chrome',
          shardTestFiles: false,
            chromeOptions: {
              args: [
                "--window-size=414,736"
              ]
          },
        },
```

and i receive error

```
E/launcher - invalid argument: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from invalid argument: cannot parse args
from invalid argument: must be a list
```

but if i try to start with conf.js `chromeOptions: {args: [--window-size=414,736]}` without Gruntfile.js it works.

Comment: Can you paste the config of multiCapabilities?

Comment: why don't you paste it to config itself?

Comment: @huan feng, if I paste it to conf.js protractor will run tests in parallel, but i want to use it independently, may be I don't understand something?

Comment: @Sergey Pleshakov, I have different settings for protractor and it will be complicated for editing

Comment: my framework covers 15 applications, dozen of clients, 4 environment each, optional integration with browserstack, bunch of reporters including video reporter and this is just a tip of the iceberg... I tend to separate the process into layers. Grunt layer is only for taking parameters and doing pretasks. Protractor config is for protractor, so all related logic is there. When my config became 400 lines I just broke it into like 10 files for better maintenance. And works fine